# Disable subtitles by default in a MP4 file using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, subtitles

Is there a way to disable (not to remove) subtitles by default using FFmpeg, I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -disposition:s:s:0 0 output.mp4
```

but it didn't work.

I searched on the internet and although many people asked the same question, I couldn't find an answer

Comment: What program are you using to play the files? For example in some of my files VLC always shows subtitles regardless of whether the subtitles are set "on" as indicated by the file, other players do not have the same behaviour.

Comment: The program I use to play the files is: mpv

Comment: @Nau According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673094/4926757), there is an option `-default_mode infer_no_subs`, but it applies MKV file format (I think it's not going to work with MP4).